# Completely disable the volume OSD in Gnome

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04, notification, volume-control

I'm trying to completely disable Gnome's on-screen-display overlay for volume (I would also like to disable the other overlays too, e.g. Keyboard illumination and screen brightness).

The reason being, when I'm playing games in full screen and adjust the volume, the OSD forces the game I'm playing to minimise, which is really annoying.

I've tried the [Move OSD Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1220/move-osd-windows/) Gnome extension which can hide the OSD, but this doesn't solve the problem, as whilst it does hide the OSD, Gnome must still attempt to render it, as my game still minimises.

With the searching I've done on the web, it's apparent that I'm not going to find a built in tweak, option or extension to achieve this, so I'm hoping I might be able to remove a component of Gnome from my system to achieve this, or forcibly (but cleanly) break this feature somehow.

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 with Gnome 3.32.1. If it matters, I'm using a 2015 Macbook pro, and it's the keyboard media controls that trigger the OSD. (I don't want to disable the media keys, as I want to be able to adjust volume in game).

Comment: Having the same issue, but i'd prefer not requiring custom keyboard shortcuts. There's gotta be a better way!

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to find an alternative solution to this problem that bypassed the Gnome volume OSD completely, though it might not work for all.

I've simply removed the Gnome keyboard shortcuts for the volume control, and instead created some custom keyboard shortcuts that run a command. The commands I've used are simply:

Volume Up `pactl set-sink-volume 0 +5%`
Volume Down `pactl set-sink-volume 0 -5%`
Mute `pactl set-sink-volume 0 0%`

It's not ideal, as I can't unmute with the mute key, but it solves the immediate problem.

Comment: for mute you can use `pactl set-sink-mute 0 toggle`, so you can mute/unmute with the same key

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you Bryan and derhoch