# remove the volume OSD in Gnome

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04, volume-control

ubuntu 19.04
when I scroll the mouse over the sound icon. in the middle of the screen pop up volume icon.
I just want to remove it from my system. it is useless and disturbing while watching movies.
please help

Comment: removing needs editing core files and compiling.. l0t 0f stuff t0 d0.. I think by editing shell theme you currently using.. you can make it invisible..

Comment: how can I edit?

Comment: I am trying to do it in my system.. wait for sometime.. mean while any expert can write a extension for it which is proper way..

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1164579/739431

Comment: it is just control from terminal. it dont remove pop up

Comment: just for info i shared that link as your question and OPs question is almost same..

Answer (score 1):

***Warning: Editing gdm3.css file/ its orginal files have serious issues if small mistakes are occurred while editing.. you can not login to your system.. to bring back the things to normal you need special support..*** Proceed with your own

Below is just a temporary workaround until some expert writes extension to disable the OSD for Volume Change..

Ubuntu 18.04
user-shell-theme: `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`

`sudo -H gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`

already edited code:

```
/* OSD */
.osd-window {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  spacing: 1em;
  margin: 32px;
  min-width: 64px;
  min-height: 64px; }
  .osd-window .osd-monitor-label {
    font-size: 3em; }
  .osd-window .level {
    height: 0.6em;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: transparent; }
  .osd-window .level-bar {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 0.3em; }
```

Other Area:

```
.osd-window

      { color: transparent;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 12px;
      padding: 12px; }

    .resize-popup,
    .switcher-list, .workspace-switcher-container {
      color: #eeeeec;
      background-color: #3f3e39;
      border: 1px solid rgba(238, 238, 236, 0.2);
      border-radius: 12px;
      padding: 12px; }
```

You need to look out for the `transparent` text in above codes..

look at the bottom right corner on volume icon..

[image]