# How to change volume indication overlay

Tags: gui, volume-control

The volume overlay is quite intrusive when I screen-share during meetings and change my volume. Is there a way to change the UI? Maybe make it smaller and out of the way like windows?

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version? What's your Ubuntu flavor (variant)?

Comment: Does [this answer your question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1416310/167115)? The ["move osd windows" extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1220/move-osd-windows/) is available for Gnome Shell versions up to 3.38. Please let us know if this answer doesn't work for you.

Comment: Another solution would be to bypass gnome shell and set [custom keyboard shortcuts to adjust the volume](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164586/167115). Here, you would set each of these commands to a [custom keyboard shortcut](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en). It should be noted that you cannot use an existing key combo and you may have to log out and log back in after setting a new shortcut.

Comment: So if you normally use the volume keys on your keyboard, you might be able to [disable the existing volume shortcuts and then create new shortcuts using the same keys](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-can-i-disable-popup-notification-for-volume-control/6968/3#post_4). Although that was on the Mate forums, the basic idea should still apply.